# ssis missing constraint lines

Tags: visual-studio-2008, ssis

I am having a strange issue with some of my packages in the same project.

When I reload the project some of the constraint connectors are not appearing visually.  I know that they are there because if I try to draw them again I get the error:

```
Cannot create connector.
Only one workflow can exist between the same two executables.
```

Also the package runs correctly.

Can I get the lines to reappear?

I am using visual studio 2008.  The objects affected are in a for loop in a sequence container

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was having the same trouble.  If you collapse the Sequence Container, then expand it again, they show up again.

Answer (score 2):

Well when I have had issues with the screen not properly showing what really is there, usually it is because I have too much junk open on my machine, So I go back and close the 56 query windows I have open and the 700+page functional spec, and all 10 of the Windows Explorer windows and Outlook and the 6 Excel spreadsheets and the offending SSIS package and then reopen it and it usually works (alhtough occasionally I have had to reboot.)

Comment: Good thought, but I don't have anything else open except out look.  What I did was move the contents from the loop out of the loop and the lines appeared, then put in back in the loop.